Which multi-wallet connect to use in 2024?
hope all is well. I am relatively new to the space and I was wondering for an NFT marketplace, which multi-wallet connect should I use? More specifically, it seems that most web3 apps use web3modal, rainbowkit, thirdweb, and strictly wagmi. Is there a current preference in the community for one library over the other? Thanks.

Right now Web3Modal is widely used for Web3 marketplaces, supporting a range of wallets like MetaMask, WalletConnect, and Coinbase Wallet. It offers a good user experience, security, and easy integration. Some also using Wagmi for a nicer UI, so the choice depends on your preference.

Also always go with a vendor-neutral open source library instead of vendor locked in SDKs like ThirdWeb. Otherwise you are in for the pain in the future.

@MikkoOhtamaa Thanks for the insight. I decided to go with Web3Modal + ethers v6. Maybe I will switch to Web3Modal + wagmi in the future.

I don’t think Wagmi is the best choice. As far as I know ethersjs is mostly used for development and depends on the backend.
